# What is the exact connection between BV-Functions and their weak derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, bounded-variation, weak-derivatives

let $ \Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be open. I have read that $u : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is of bounded Variation if there exist a Radon measure $\mu : \mathcal{B}(\Omega) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ with 
$\displaystyle \int_\Omega u div\varphi d\mathcal{L}^n = \displaystyle\int_\Omega \langle\varphi, \mu \rangle, \forall \varphi \in C_c^1(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^n)$, with $\mathcal{L}^n$ denoting the n-dimensional Lebesgue-measure. And $\mu$ is exactly the measure corresponding to the weak derivative or the measure corresponding to the distributional derivative? I'm not entirely sure what the difference between these 2 is. And what does corresponding mean in this context?

Comment: The "weak derivative" and "distributional derivative" is basically the same thing. Usually "weak derivative" is used to denote the distributional derivative of a function when this derivative is also a function (typically in the context of Sobolev spaces). Since in the context of BV functions the distributional derivative is a measure, I would call this measue $\mu$ the distributional derivative of $u$ in your case.

Comment: alright, thank you. could you elaborate on why in the context of BV-Functions the weak derivative is a measure?

Comment: By definition, $BV(\Omega)$ consists of the functions in $L^1(\Omega)$ whose distributional derivative is a finite Radon measure.